# How define cURL request and block that? That's impossible?

Tags: php, security, curl, http-headers

One site with same sphere what and my site blocks cURL requests. I read server can't define real browser and cURL. It's impossible. And I want to repeat their defense from bots and cURL requests for my own site.

But it is not just stupid check user-agent. They required full copy headers like real browsers, otherwise you get follow message:

> If you are not a bot, please copy the report and send it to our
> support team

And that is not the end, because if you copy full browser's request headers for cURL, you get empty page with generating cookie (as far i understand that's JWT or something like that).
I checked behavior of browsers: browsers have that cookie, but if that's your first connection with their site, their server return into headers `set-cookie` with that JWT, and normal web-page.

I notice Ethernet says - defining cURL request is impossible, but anyway they could do it, and I don't know how. That's really interesting.
I think how they do it. I compared response headers for cURL and real browser (for first contact):

Header response for real browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 15:42:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
set-cookie: spid=some_spid_value; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: spsc=some_spsc_value; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
X-SP-CRID: 1909462187:1
```

Header response for cURL (with copy headers of request like real browser):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 15:43:28 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache
expires: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 15:4327 GMT
pragma: no-cache
content-type: text/html
X-SP-CRID: 1913083470:1
```

If compare this headers, you can see apart from `set-cookie`, server sends some other headers for cURL and browser. Extra headers for cURL: `access-control-allow-origin`, `expires`, `cache-control`, `pragma`. Extra headers for browser: `vary`, `content-encoding`, `strict-transport-security`. That says about defining cURL requests. I repeated my experiment with Postman, and I used same headers of real browser. And i got the same result like with cURL.

I don't know how they does it, but I think they see on some signature of request (may be SSL or other meta-data) and then define that is cURL or not.

Comment: There's no way for us to answer how various sites do their validation checks. It's probably heuristics related to timing.

Comment: `If you are not a bot, please copy the report and send it to our support team`. Why don't you ask them?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am not a friend for them. I doubt they help me.